# Any way to redirect to another page on my site with PHP, besides header()?

Tags: php

I am programming my first PHP web app and I have a question:

If I want to redirect the user to another page on the same site, under x conditions, how can I do it?

Is there a way, besides using header ()? I want to use relative paths so I was wondering if there is another way.

Basically my page receives a POST variable, and I want to make it so that if the variable does not meet certain requirements the page redirects you to a different page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can create absolute paths on server sid by using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and the like.
- You can use javascript but this will of course only work if Javascript is enabled.
- You can use header() with Refresh instead of Location which (as far as I remember) accepts relative addresses) edit: Refresh is NOT standardized, but works in every browser I know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `META` tag that causes a refresh, or you can use JavaScript to set `document.location`. But why? You can already get the current URL in the various `$_SERVER` indexes, and it's easy enough to convert to an absolute URL.

Answer (score 1):

Header is going to be your best bet.  It happens on the server side, and doesn't give the user a choice.  You can also use a javascript redirect, but it wont work if the client has javascript disabled. You can also do an HTML META Refresh redirect, which users can also turn off.

Answer (score 1):

Header is the best way. If you want to use a relative path try this:

```
$curPath = dirname($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ) . "../relative/path";
```

You can also use the meta refresh method Don't do this because it can screw up the users back button.:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=relative/path"" />
```

You can also use some javascript:

```
<script>window.location="relative/path"</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your doc head try:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.com/" />
```

Probably not a best practice though.